# How to get readable text (text with anti-aliasing) after converting PDF to image?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have used ghostscript on a PDF document with text. Text looks like black and white map of bits. How can I get the image with readable text?

```
-r96
-dTextAlphaBits=1 
-sDEVICE=png16m
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the higher resolution for your output image, say **-r300** set -**dTextAlphaBits=4** and **-sDEVICE=pnggray**

```
-dTextAlphaBits=n
-dGraphicsAlphaBits=n
```

These options control the use of subsample antialiasing. Their use is highly recommended for producing high quality rasterizations of the input files. The size of the subsampling box n should be 4 for optimum output, but smaller values can be used for faster rendering. Antialiasing is enabled separately for text and graphics content.

Comment: Thank you for recommendations, but I do not need gray-scaled image. So, I have to find out optimal TextAlphaBits for my text.